# Get full list of Autocomplete entries?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

How can I get a full list of saved auto-complete entries for a specific textbox name in [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)?

Pressing the <kbd>↓</kbd> key with the textbox focused, gives me 6 random entries.

Typing <kbd>s</kbd> gives me another 6 entries - this time beginning with `s`.

But how can I get the full list? It's for my own PC, so I have admin rights - nothing underhand going on.

It is, however, on a domain which I do not own.

I do use the *Sign-in* feature of Chrome, if that makes any difference.

The text box in question is:

```
<input type="search" class="inputbox" name="q">
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Download and run [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)
2. Close Chrome (or copy the file to another location and open that)
3. Open `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data` with the db browser

   - For OS X, the relevant file is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Web Data`
   - For Linux, `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Data`
   - For other OS's, this will point you in the right direction: [Where does Chrome save its SQLite database to? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936878/where-does-chrome-save-its-sqlite-database-to)
4. <kbd>Browse Data</kbd>
5. Table: `autofill`

Alternatively, to get the autofill entries for a specific input name, click <kbd>Execute SQL</kbd> and execute this:

```
select *
from autofill
where name = 'q'
order by value asc
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in 2021 I think. Getting the error: ```Could not open database file. Reason: database is locked```

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE Did you close Chrome (and confirm it’s processes have been killed in Task Manager) before trying to open the database in SQLite Browser? Searching your error online it seems there might be a lot of solutions, E.G. https://www.arysontechnologies.com/blog/fix-sqlite-error-database-locked/

Comment: I'm stupid and didn't close all chrome tabs :D it still works, thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! But take a backup before you do this in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX, the relevant file is located at

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Web Data`

(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936878/where-does-chrome-save-its-sqlite-database-to)