# Saving chrome address bar autocompletes

Tags: google-chrome, backup, browser

I am switching laptops soon and would like to backup my address bar's suggestions for websites. As in the autocomplete suggestions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the following SU link as this question has been answered here. You could just backup that specific database and re-import it into your new install as well.

[Get full list of Autocomplete entries?](https://superuser.com/questions/565763/get-full-list-of-autocomplete-entries)