# how do I find the autocomplete file to fill in my name and address, etc.?

Tags: windows-10, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Please tell me where to find the autocomplete file so I can fill in my name and address, etc. so it will autofill on forms and websites.

Comment: I don't know if there is such a file, but you can edit it in Chrome Settings under "Autofill settings"

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file in `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME_HERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`. You'll need a program that can view SQLite databases like [SQLite database browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). You could also try using a text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Look under the table "autofill". You may need to close chrome first.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/598881/772197)